# Issues with nHibernate Assemblies

Tags: nhibernate, assemblies

I am in the process of creating a set of unit tests for my Fluent nHibernate project and my tests fail during setup with the following error:

```
 SetUp : System.IO.FileLoadException : Could not load file or assembly 'NHibernate,       Version=3.0.0.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I am really stumped as I have added all the necessary references, etc.  Any help would be great.

Comment: What version of fluent nhibernate are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Like Mauricio said above it's most likely you have a version mismatch.  You have an assembly that is referencing version 3.0.0.4000 of nhibernate and you do not have version 3.0.0.4000 included in your references.  If you are using Fluent NHibernate you should just go [here](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) to get the latest version of NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate.  Just use all the references in this download and you should be good.